# How to use strongly-typed model with ASPX View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to know what is the equivalent ASPX View Engine code syntax of:

`@model sinesys.ViewModel.Country` (This code must be typed in on header of Razor view page)

The code above is written using RAZOR View Engine code syntax.

Please note:

1. `ViewModel` is a namespace in the project
2. `Country` is a class as implemented below:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Mvc;

   namespace sinesys.ViewModel
   {
       public class Country
       {
           public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
           public string SelectedCountry { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the same result (which amounts to specifying a strongly-typed model for the view) using the following code in the ASPX view engine:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"   
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<sinesys.ViewModel.Country>" %>
```